Why running tera term from Jenkins does not working?
I am trying to automate sending file through serial port using tera-term software. When i run command using cmd it works. but when i try to run the same command from jenkins script it does not work.
This is the command using i used in jenkins.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm5\ttpmacro.exe" "C:\tera_term_script.TTL"
this is my ttl file
connect '/C=4 /BAUD=921600 /PARITY=N /DATA=8 /STOP=1 /V'
; Wait for the connection to establish
pause 2
; Send the file  using XMODEM protocol
xmodemsend 'C:\src\Debug\demo.bin' 2
; parametrs 0 means disconnect immediately
disconnect 0
; End of script
end

What do you mean "does not work"? What's the error message?

It just hangs. No logs. What i was able to figure out, tera tera is GUI App, since jenkins is windows service, it cant call tera term.
